# OSX - Maven installed: mvn command not recognised

Tags: macos, maven, command, installation, environment

I've tried a bunch of previous solutions (see below) but something must be wrong with my environment...

When trying any variant of the following:

```
mvn -v
mvn -version
mvn --version
mvn3 -version
mvn3 --version
```

All produce `~bash: mvn: command not found`

Confirming my PATH includes the maven /bin/, JAVA_HOME includes jdk home, (and even M3_HOME is maven dir, as per one thread) are as follows:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/.local/bin:/usr/local/javaPath:/Documents/MavenStuff/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin

$echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home

$echo $M3_HOME
/Documents/MavenStuff/apache-maven-3.5.2/
```

The /apache-maven-3.5.2/ directory contains the uncompressed maven folder, straight from the website:

```
apache-maven-3.5.2/ user1$ ls -l
total 64
-rw-r--r--@  1 user1  1373174850  20943 18 Oct 08:59 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--@  1 user1  1373174850    182 18 Oct 08:59 NOTICE
-rw-r--r--@  1 user1  1373174850   2544 18 Oct 08:55 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user1  1373174850    272  9 Mar 00:21 bin
drwxr-xr-x@  3 user1  1373174850    102  9 Mar 00:21 boot
drwxr-xr-x@  5 user1  1373174850    170  9 Mar 00:21 conf
drwxr-xr-x@ 83 user1  1373174850   2822  9 Mar 00:21 lib
```

Why won't maven work? :\

Comment: Remove M3_HOME and keep the bin path only in PATH variable. Can you show an `ls -al` inside apache-maven-3.5.2/bin directory?

Comment: Sure, done. https://imgur.com/a/MAoRt @khmarbaise

Comment: I wrote `ls -al` on that directory and not only the files..an output like above from the apache-maven-3.5.2 directory...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kA6Se @khmarbaise

Comment: Do you really have a Document directory starting from root location or ise in your user home directory instead ? Apart from that have you tried to call mvn via absolute path like `/Documents/MavenStuff/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin/mvn --version`?

Comment: Document dir is in user home directory I think. `cd` takes me to the parent dir which contains /Document/.

The absolute path call you just listed works -- I get an answer with maven version

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/fHQEw @khmarbaise

Comment: Ah so your entry in PATH is wrong which means you have to give the full path in your PATH variable...including /Users/user1/....

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have boiled down to a syntax error in the `PATH` directory.

Once I removed the `/` from in front of the maven bin directory in `PATH`, it worked. So,

Old $PATH:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/.local/bin:/usr/local/javaPath:/Documents/MavenStuff/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin

New $PATH:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/.local/bin:/usr/local/javaPath:Documents/MavenStuff/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin

The latter works. Note the offending `/` is gone.

Edit: The above does work but only from home directory. Below works anywhere:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/.local/bin:/usr/local/javaPath:~/Documents/MavenStuff/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin

Comment: This means that you installed maven in your private directory. Not sure it's a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a bit old but I just had a similar issue trying to install mvn on OSX. I resolved this by using homebrew to install mvn using `brew install maven` after this command was run i could use `mvn clean package` as usual.

Thought this might help incase anyone is installing mvn a different way, as this installation method allows you to use `mvn` without explicitly declaring its PATH.